# INSERT IGNORE INTO producing error 1109 unknown table in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to create an INSERT IGNORE INTO statement, to pull user details from a new reglist table into an existing membership table, omitting rows where the email address is already in the membership table.

Here's what I have so far:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO members (Email, FirstName, LastName, SectorName, ECR, Gender, UserLocation, JoinDate)
    SELECT Email, FirstName, LastName, SectorName, ECR, Gender, UserLocation, RegDate
    FROM reglist1 as r
    WHERE r.Email NOT IN (SELECT Email FROM members);
```

However, I am getting: "Error Code: 1109. Unknown table 'members' in where clause"

When I run `SELECT Email FROM members;` alone it works fine. So I can't figure out why the table is unknown when included in the INSERT statement.

I've tried aliasing members in the first line `members m` but that flags as an error even before attempting to run.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think I've just cracked it - there was an 'after insert' trigger set up which has an error in it. Once I drop the trigger it works. Phew! Thank you :)

Comment: Hidden side effects like that -- a reason to avoid Triggers.